Can we perform selective injections as a payload to test vulnerabilities in zap with python?
We are trying to see a possibility of performing selective injections like SQL injection, XSS injection etc., as a payload in fuzzing to test vulnerabilities in web applications with python.
Use-case:

Select an URL end-point or an input field in request.
Add payload (for example SQL Injection).
Start the fuzz.
Note the results.

Two queries as below:

Can we control what end-points, input fields can be considered and
what pay loads can be sent in ZAP using python?

If yes, can we consider this as equivalent to active sql injection
in fuzzing in ZAP tool?



also asked on https://groups.google.com/g/zaproxy-develop/c/bPurBBcGgMg/m/fxbo3qsXAQAJ where I'm answering ;)
